# Python: Adding method for number

Tags: python, date, syntactic-sugar

Being tempted with Ruby I want to add some syntactic sugar in working with dates in python.
How can I implement this method: (3).days.ago() or (4).days.from_now()?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I found similar feature in https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/sure but investigating the code will take some time. I try to find an faster way to do this.

Comment: you want to write ruby in python?  :)

Comment: no one would be able to understand you lost-in-translation python script.

Comment: +1 .. fun idea, but why don't you just use ruby?

Comment: @Nozim: Python is not Ruby. You can't monkeypatch built-in types. Cleverness may be cool, but readability counts.

Comment: @TimPietzcker how does https://github.com/gabrielfalcao/sure do it?  It seems to work ..

Comment: I know that Python is not Ruby. Please don't flood the topic if you can't help. Will be VERY appreciated.

Comment: @Nozim: What that "sure" project is doing is an evil hack and should not be done.  It relies on details of the C internals of Python and could break with a new Python version.  Unless you are just doing this as a toy to mess around, forget it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a syntax close to what you want, subclass *int* to add new methods (the built-in *int* type is unmodifiable so a subclass is the only option for extending integer behaviors).  Compute the date offsets using [*timedelta*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) in the [*datetime module*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#module-datetime):

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta

>>> class Int(int):
        def days_ago(self):
            return date.today() - timedelta(days=self)
        def days_from_now(self):
            return date.today() + timedelta(days=self)

>>> Int(3).days_ago()
datetime.date(2013, 4, 5)
>>> Int(4).days_from_now()
datetime.date(2013, 4, 12)
```

Comment: I want to wrap this functions with mine

Comment: The problem is in implementing "(3).days.ago()" in python but not in getting date. It's just one of applications of this trick.

Comment: @Nozim your wants don't intersect with what the language provides.